# What does the word ゆける signify?

Tags: grammar, definitions

I have the sentence:

> この国に生まれ老い、良かったと死んでゆける高齢化社会。

This is the first time I've seen 「死んでゆける」 or 「ゆける」. What does it mean? Is this a grammatical form? I also tried looking up more examples with 「ゆける」[here](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%86%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B), but there are only a few, and I'm not able to derive the meaning yet.

Comment: We also write it as 死んで'い'ける, the potential form of 死んで'い'く. (死んで'ゆ'ける and 死んで'ゆ'く sound more literary to me.) We also have 「[生]{う}まれてくる」、「[生]{い}きていく(生きてゆく)」...

Comment: ところで・・・the いく in 死んでいく has a nuance of "離れる/going away" and the いく in 生きていく has a nuance of "続ける/~~on, continue ~~"

Answer (score 6):

yuke-ru (行ける) is a verb meaning "can go" or "is possible". It derives from the potential form of the verb yuk- (行く). "an aging society in which one can die being grateful for being born and growing old in this country"

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even consider「行く」when I should have. Is it normal for it to be written in hiragana as opposed to kanji?

Comment: Either is fine, but I typically see it in hiragana. Consider it being written in kanji: is it read ikeru or yukeru? That is one motivation.

Comment: Since it's speaking of dying, wouldn't it more likely be `逝ける`?

Comment: It's typically written in hiragana when used with the って form of the verb, as is くる.

Comment: The te-form of ゆく is ゆいて (イ音便) instead of ゆって (促音便), but it was obsolete. ゆく(行く) was much popular than いく(行く) in classical Japanese, but we usually use いく and read 行く as いく at present time.

Comment: @Gradius Note though that both iku and yuku are already extant in Nara period texts.